# How can I use jQuery.load to replace a div including the div

Tags: jquery

I have a div with the id of "secondHeader" and I want to replace that entire div with another div with the same id of "secondHeader" but instead of replacing it , it just adds the loaded div inside the first one.

```
$("#secondHeader").load("/logged-in-content.html #secondHeader");
```

This is what happens...

```
<div id="secondHeader"><div id="secondHeader"></div></div>
```

What I want to happen is the secondHeader div from the ajax load to totally replace the secondHeader in the initial page.

I know it sounds dumb, but here's what I'm trying to accomplish...When a user is not logged in, they see a non-logged in header. I am using ajax to allow the person to log into the site and I want to replace the non-logged in header with the logged in one via ajax.

I have tried everything I know such as...

```
$("#secondHeader").replaceWith($("#secondHeader").load("/logged-in-content.html #secondHeader"));
```

...and using .remove() before hand...

Any ideas?

Comment: I know this is extremely old but you could also do this: $("#secondHeader").parent().load("/logged-in-content.html #secondHeader");

Comment: @jth_92 If that's a good idea put it up as an answer and let it fend for itself. As it happens that overwrites all the siblings of #secondHeader, so it should be at the bottom.

Comment: @Noumenon This is true that it will overwrite the siblings; in the DOM posted though, the inner #secondHeader has no siblings. It appears to be a wrapper of all the content (i.e. the header that is to be replaced). Being a wrapper of all the content, no siblings are affected.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I think the best way is to use get instead of load. In your case you can do like this:

```
$.get("/logged-in-content.html #secondHeader", function(data) {
     $("#secondHeader").replaceWith(data);
});
```

[Edit: removed a paren]

Update:
If /logged-in-content.html has more than just the code you need, you can wrap the returning data in another jQuery object and use .find() to extract the container.
Try this:

$("#secondHeader").replaceWith($(data).find("#secondHeader"));

Comment: I don't understand why this is the accepted and most upvoted answer. The variable `data` there will actually contain the entire contents of `/logged-in-content.html` not `/logged-in-content.html #secondHeader` as you might assume from the code. So `$("#secondHeader").replaceWith(data);` is actually inserting the entire page there.

Comment: This solution actually worked for me because I was using it to 'get' a php file that contained only the code that I wanted. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @srcspider that explains the recursion I experienced and the resulting modernist website.  Other than the browser crashing it looked neat!

Comment: Why is this accepted? Adding a fragment identifier to the URL is only supported by `.load()`, not `$.get()`.

Answer (score 69):

Could you refine your selector in the load() method?

For example,

```
$("#secondHeader").load("/logged-in-content.html #secondHeader > *");
```

This way, you're not grabbing the div itself, you're grabbing its contents.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I actually tried that, but it comes back really funky and not all as one cohesive div.

Comment: how about loading the remote content into a temporary div. Then on the callback, after doing this, simply relocate the contents as desired. This would "work", but probably not an ideal or terribly elegant approach. The key will be to do this in the "load" method's callback, to allow time for the content to finish retrieving. I looked at your original post again and perhaps this timing issue is what is causing your original ideas not to work for you...

Comment: Hmmm, interesting that the `#secondHeader > *` selector doesn't work for you. I just today had a similar need (I want just the contents of the remote div, not the enclosing div itself) and thought I'd give this a try. It works great in my case, exactly as expected.

Comment: Maybe the probleme was due to the fact that, using load we will get only the innerhtml of the loaded page. Which means that script tags will not be loaded. At least with chrome.

Comment: Note that this will **not** load text nodes directly below `#secondHeader`

Comment: The same technique is used in this CSS tricks [AJAX loading article](https://css-tricks.com/ajax-load-container-contents/):  `$("#area").load("something.html #area > *");`

Comment: How this is not the accepted answer is beyond me.. This is by far the simplest and tidiest way to do this.

Answer (score 45):

Another way that worked best for me:

```
$('#div_to_replace').load('/ajax/loader', function() {
    $(this).children(':first').unwrap();
});
```

Comment: This is the only suggestion in this thread that worked for me, the others would just replace the div with the entire HTML

Comment: preserves the use and spirit of `.load()`

Answer (score 11):

**Final Answer:**

```
$.fn.loadWith = function(u){var c=$(this);$.get(u,function(d){c.replaceWith(d);});};
$("#test").loadWith("somelink.html");
```

jQuery [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) adds the response INTO the element selected. jQuery's [replaceWith](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) REPLACES the selected element.

```
<div id="curElement">start</div>

$("#curElement").load("somelink.html");
will result in:
<div id="curElement">What ever was in somelink.html</div>


$("#curElement").replaceWith("somelink.html");
will result in:
What ever was in somelink.html
```

I suggest adding a function to jQuery that does both:

```
$.fn.loadWith = function(u){
    var c=$(this);
    $.get(u,function(d){
        c.replaceWith(d);
    });
};
$("#test").loadWith("somelink.html");
```

Answer (score 5):

Using $.get() worked for me but I had to extract the container from the response document first:

```
$.get("/page.html", function (data) {
    var elem = $(data).find('#container');
    $("#puthere").replaceWith(elem);
});
```

Comment: it gives an blank page only

Answer (score 3):

I always have a jQuery function defined like this:

```
    jQuery.fn.loadOuter = function( url, callback )
    {
        var toLoad = $(this);
        $.get(url, function( data ) {
            toLoad.replaceWith( data );
            if (callback != null && callback != undefined)
                callback();
        });
    }
```

Then I can either say

```
$(...).load(url)
```

or

```
$(...).loadOuter(url)
```

The second one does what you want to do. I also have a function called loadInner which just calls load for what its worth.

Answer (score 2):

$.load isn't really the best choice here since that function's intended to just fill in the contents of a div, as you've seen.  You can just use [$.get](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.get) instead and set the callback function to replace your original div, or change logged-in-content.html to exclude the div.

Also be aware that as a Javascript-based solution, if your users look at the source, they'll see that they can get access to logged-in-content.html by just typing it in their address bar if you're not securing it somehow else.

Comment: I would recommend keeping your headers in separate files and loading them as needed.

Comment: It's the same header, and it uses a loginview asp.net control. I don't think it would matter much if they were in different files cause I would have the same problem.

I will try to the $.get method, but what I really liked about the $.load was that I could select only the part I wanted/needed and I don't think I can use that functionality with $.get

Answer (score 1):

```
var target = '#secondHeader';
var pathname = '/logged-in-content.html';
var source = pathname + ' ' + target;
var temp = jQuery('<div></div>');
temp.load(source, function() {
jQuery(target).replaceWith(temp.contents());
});
```

or as function

```
$.fn.replaceWithRemote = function( source, callback )   {
    var target = $(this);
    var temp = $('<div></div>');
    temp.load(source, function() {
        target.replaceWith(temp.contents());
        if (callback != null){
            callback();
        }
    });
}

$('#secondHeader').replaceWithRemote('/logged-in-content.html #secondHeader');
```

Answer (score 1):

After you have loaded the content, find its children `#second` and unwrap it.

```
$("#secondHeader").children().unwrap();
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to wrap in div before inserting it.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/logged-in-content.html",
    success: function(response){
        var loadedheader = $("<div/>").append(
        response.replace(/<script(.|\s)*?\/script>/g, "")
        ).find('#secondHeader > *').html();
        $("#secondHeader").append(loadedheader);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the code Jourkey. I just tried it and it doesn't seem to do what I need it to. It just takes individual elements and adds them one at a time in a non-hierarchical fashion so it doesn't keep the same dom structure as I need it to have. I'm still trying to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add a container DIV around your "secondHeader" div? Then you'd use:

```
$('#secondHeaderContainer').load('/logged-in-content.html #secondHeader');
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My solution that worked for me was that I **embedded a child div inside and updated the child div:**

**HTML:**

```
<div id="secondHeader">
  <div id="secondHeaderChild">
     What currently is in secondHeader goes here....
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Ajax:**

```
$("#secondHeader").replaceWith($("#secondHeader").load("/logged-in-content.html 
#secondHeaderChild"));
```

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue as well, but I was able to use `.load` by restructuring the code like so: (jade)

```
div#view
   div.content
      block content
```

and the script like so...

```
$("#view").load( $(this).attr("href") + " div.content" )
```

so target the child instead of the same tag.