# back after loading external html

Tags: jquery, upload, back

Been racking my brain (I'm new to jQuery etc) on this one.

I've managed to load an external html file into my page on click but can't figure out how to go back to what was previously in that div.

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.project').click(function(e){
      var link = $(this).attr('rel');
      event.preventDefault();
      $('#main').empty();
      $('#main').load(link);
   });
});
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: `.load` will `empty` the div before loading the new content. However you can try to clone the div before `.load` and use the clone as you want. Note: `$('#main').empty();` and then `$('#main').load(link);` is redundant as `.load` will empty the div.

Answer (score 3):

you can clone the div and store it in a variable:

```
 var whatWas = $('#main').clone();
```

Answer (score 1):

`.load` will empty the div before loading the new content. However you can try to clone the div before `.load` and use the clone as you want.

Note: `$('#main').empty();` and then `$('#main').load(link);` is redundant as `.load` will empty the div.

Try like below,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var $mainClone = null;
   $('.project').click(function(e){
      var link = $(this).attr('rel');
      event.preventDefault();
      $mainClone = $('#main').clone().prop('id', 'main-clone'); //clone and change ID
      $('#main').load(link);
   });      
});
```

later you can replace the `#main` content using below,

```
$('#main').html($mainClone.html())
```

Comment: @Bennjamin_ Try to set up what you have http://www.jsFiddle.net where we can try it out.

Comment: It's like this. http://jsfiddle.net/vgh64/7/
I don't know how to setup ajax in jsfiddle though. When you click the picture there should be a "back link" which will be the event to go back to the cloned content. Does that make sense?

Comment: `$('#main').html($mainClone.html())` does not exactly replace the div, it puts a new copy of the div inside the old one. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344030/how-can-i-use-jquery-load-to-replace-a-div-including-the-div for actual replacement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store what was in the div before you loaded the new HTML.  Most likely you need to store this in a global variable.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var whatWas;

    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('.project').click(function(e){
          global whatWas;
          var link = $(this).attr('rel');
          whatWas = $('#main').clone();
          event.preventDefault();
          $('#main').empty();
          $('#main').load(link);
       });
    });

    ...
    //here you need to catch the event that you want to use to load the original content back into the div
</script>
```

When you want to go back you can replace the div with the original HTML like this:

```
$('#main').html(whatWas);
```