# jquery return value by php echo command

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have these codes:

Contents of **main.php**:

**Javascript**

```
function grab()
{
    $("#div_id").load("/test.php");
}
```

**HTML & PHP**

```
<? $original_value = 'Original content'; ?>

<div id='div_id'><?=original_value;?></div>

<form action="javascript:grab($('#div_id').val())">

    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit">

</form>
```

also **test.php**

```
<?... 
$update_value = "Update content";
echo $update_value;?>
```

the result of test.php will be written into #div_id and the result for div content is:

```
Original content
Update content
```

But i like to overwrite original div value and the result should be:

```
Update content
```

I mean `echo` append a new line in #div_id, but i like to overwrite existing #div_id content.

Comment: i don't understand the question

Comment: Question not clear , please specify the scenario

Comment: I presume the contents of test.php should be written into #div_id.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use jQuery.load to replace a div including the div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344030/how-can-i-use-jquery-load-to-replace-a-div-including-the-div)

Comment: `<form action="javascript:grab($('#div_id').val())">` does not seem right. The `action`-attribute is for urls.

Comment: i explained about div content...i hope it is clear now

Comment: @Amir did you include jQuery in main.php? Seeing nothing wrong with your code otherwise... http://fiddle.jshell.net/2nwwG/show/

Comment: @extramaster Yes , jquery is included already and it works...

Comment: It sounds like `.load` is **appending** the contents of `/test.php` to #div_id, but it should actually replace everything.

Comment: @Amir As far as I can see, everything should work as you want, but  are those pieces of code a parts of real code? It looks like you have broken HTML in browser. For instance, this `<div id='div_id'><?=original_value;?></div>` may finally be parsed by browser like this: `<div id='div_id'></div><div>Original content</div>` (Possibly - because of some not closed tag in original content). Open developer tools and see exact structure of DOM in that place (F12 in all browser, you may need to install firebug for FF)

Comment: @FAngel ...Yes it is part of real code...but i simplify most of the codes...and yes , it will be <div>Original content</div> for the browsers.

Comment: @Amir are you saying that it is `<div>Original content</div>` and NOT `<div id="div_id">Original content</div>`?

Comment: @FAngel.. after run in browser for the first time it will be `<div id="div_id">Original content</div>`... please note to:`<? $original_value = 'Original content'; ?>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the following in your code.

1. Remove the javascript in your action attribute. It doesn't look right.

   ```
   <form action="">

       <input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit">

   </form>
   ```
2. Add the following javascript.

   ```
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
           e.preventDefault(); // Prevents the default submit action. 
           // Otherwise the page is reloaded.

           grab();
       });
   });
   ```

The function `grab` will be called when the form is submitted. I'm not sure if this is what you want, but you should see the new contents in the div.

**UPDATE 1:**

I have removed the parameter from `grab` because the function doesn't need one.

Comment: action works perfectly...but my question is about #div_id content

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the content while the current code appends it, change code to:

```
$("#div_id").empty().load("/test.php");
```

Comment: @AlexTMH: `.load()` does **not** append, it replaces, so `empty()` is irrelevant.