# Use jQuery's .load() to load page fragments but only get contents of selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-load

I am using jQuery's `.load()` page fragments method to reload a piece of my page:

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
    $("#box").load('/ajax/box/ #box');
});
```

It works, however this is causing an error because after the contents is loaded. Since this function essentially uses `.innerHTML` it is replacing the code on the inside of my `div`. The HTML result looks like:

```
<div id="box">
    <div id="box">
        <!-- this is my page -->
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried using `.parent()` but removes all other `div`s in the parent.

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
    $("#box").parent().load('/ajax/box/ #box');
});
```

Essentially this is what I am trying to do (I know the code below is invalid, but that represents what I am trying to accomplish):

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
    $("#box").load('/ajax/box/ $('#box').html()');
});
```

Is there a way I can make `#box` be **replaced** by `#box`?
One thing to keep in mind is that I cannot edit the HTML, so this needs to happen with jQuery only.

Comment: Same problem is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344030/how-can-i-use-jquery-load-to-replace-a-div-including-the-div -- Recommended answer is use a `$.get` call, and inside the callback run a `replaceWith` on the targeted element.

Comment: That will not work. Read the comment in the accepted answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/5300738/1893629

Comment: Could you use `unwrap()`? Something like: `$("#box").load('/ajax/box/ #box', function() { $(this).find("#" + this.id).unwrap() });`

Comment: Sort of worked. I had to manually enter the `id`. But now it is causing another error in console whenever I try and load the data a second time... `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`

Comment: Well...that's a new one..only happens on a second `load` function, or any jQ func?

Comment: This form is loaded through a modal. It only happens when I try and load that particular modal. Other ones are working fine.

Comment: I think the issue has to do with something else, I may move just ask another question about.

Comment: @tymeJV just posted new question here related to the load issue http://stackoverflow.com/q/18196250/1893629

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add `> *` after `#box`

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
    $("#box").load('/ajax/box/ #box > *');
});
```