# jQuery's .load() function breaks modal from opening after .load() completes

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am using jQuery's [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method and [Loading Page Fragments](http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments). Below is my current code:

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
    $("#results").load('/ajax/box/ #box');
});
```

This code is in a moda, which is called when `a.ajax-modal` is clicked. The problem is that when `.load()` has completed, the `a.ajax-modal` in `#box` that was loaded into `#results` is not working... it doesn't not open the modal but instead just opens a new page. It seems like the contents of `#box` are not bound/attached to any event handlers.

Here is an outline of what is happening:

1. Load page
2. Click on `a.ajax-modal` and modal shows
3. Submit form in modal, run `.click()` function in modal
4. Content in `#results` on page refreshes
5. Click on new `a.ajax-modal` that was loaded in `#results` but modal **does not** show

Why is the modal not opening after `.load()` is complete?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No event has been added to your element because events are added when the document is ready. You need to use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method of jQuery to prevent this.

```
$(function()
    $(document).on('click', 'a.ajax-modal', function() {
       // Your code here.
    });
});
```

So the event is added to `document` instead of the element itself.

Comment: so are you saying that this needs to replace my `.ready()` function or this needs to be added in addition to inside the modal?

Comment: No, you need to put the click event on the document instead of the element.

Comment: Just change your click event to that one.