# JQuery Span and HTML Information Tag

Tags: jquery

I was wondering how one could load a text with a jquery .load() and then modify the text and display it on front of an image as an information text.

Any directions one can implement? I am really new to jquery.

Thanks

EDIT:

Sorry here is what I've tried:

```
    $().load("image1.jpg.txt");
```

But I am stuck on the idea on how to store it into a class element or variable such that I can display it. I am familiar with using html and importing an image and using css to modify and move it around, but I am confused in terms of doing the other way around such that we are loading from jquery and than putting it on the image.

Comment: [what have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) [you might want to read the jQuery api](http://api.jquery.com).

Comment: may i want to put online sample?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use jQuery.load to replace a div including the div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344030/how-can-i-use-jquery-load-to-replace-a-div-including-the-div)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understand you correctly, you could use CSS positioning elements to position a that will contain your original text below another div containing your image via CSS positioning elements:
[Positioning: W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

So...say you have two divs like this, positioned using CSS:

```
<div id="myText"></div>
<div id="myImage"></div>
```

You can then do something like this in jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $myText = $("#myText");
    $myText.text("Hello!");
    $myText.css("z-index", "2");
    $("#myImage").css("z-index", "1");
}
```

In this case it sets it on page load.

Alternatively, you can use a tooltip using bootstrap, which will display information on hover:
[Bootstrap Tooltips](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips)

Answer (score 1):

Look at example in [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html", function() {
  alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

You just shoud place it to some container on image

```
<div class='image-box'>
  <img src='...'/>
  <span id='img-description'></span>
</div>
```

in JS

```
 $( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html", function(data) {
      $('#img-description').html(data);
      //or you can change data before puting to span
    });
```

I hope you can write ccs for overlaying span on img?

Comment: How does the `.load()` load it in to the html? I don't see how they are interconnected.