# Filling a div with AJAX quadrates the column-count set in CSS3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make a div containing two columns with the text automatically flowing into the second column. To do this I'm using the [CSS3 column properties](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_columns.asp). This works like it should when the page initially loads, but when I use jQuery to fill the div with new content the column count value quadrates.

I tried to isolate the problem as far as possible, but the behavior remains the same:

http://tijmen.kervers.nl/B1.2/column-count-issue.html

And the CSS:

http://tijmen.kervers.nl/B1.2/column-count-issue.css

Next to squaring the column-count value it also scrambles the column order. I've numbered the lorem ipsum sentences to illustrate this, the order is 1324 rather than 1234.

Why is it doing this? Should I use a different jQuery method to load the content or can I somehow force a redraw of the div?

And just in case: here's the full page I'm using it for:

http://tijmen.kervers.nl/B1.2/competencies_0.4.html

Comment: Put your code on the question.  We shouldn't have to go and look elsewhere to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a simple issue (you need to replace this div vs append to it see):

```
$("div.title-competency").load("resources.html .competencies #" + this.id + " .title-competency");
```

Is creating 2 `.title-competency` divs.

Before ajax:

```
<div class="title-competency>
  <p>your text</p>
</div>
```

e.g. after your ajax loads you have

```
<div class="title-competency>
  <div class="title-competency>
     <p>your text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

You have options on is to use a wrapping div and there are some other hackier solutions in this SO Question:  [How can I use jQuery.load to replace a div including the div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344030/how-can-i-use-jquery-load-to-replace-a-div-including-the-div)

Comment: Ha, of course. I assumed load would replace the contents of the div I'm targeting with the **contents** of the div I'm loading, but apparently it loads the entire div, with tags and all. I changed the code to make it target text-container and put the stuff I'm loading in there. That has solved it, thanks!