# How to use .load() to load only contents of a certain element in a page and not the whole page?

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a page where users can add, edit & update a few segments. I have all of these segments in an external page and use jquery .load() function to accomplish this task. But, I am concerned about a few things like:

**1. Problem**

Say my page has one of the segments '#area' which I want to update and is like this

```
<div id="area">
    <!-- Contents -->
</div>
```

The code `$("#area").load("something.html #area");` gives the following result

```
<div id="area">
  <div id="area">
    <!-- Contents -->
  </div>
</div>
```

And whatever triggered that action, if you did it again, would lead to even more nesting (bad).

Solution

i. explained [here](https://css-tricks.com/ajax-load-container-contents/)

```js
$("#area").load("something.html #area > *");
```

ii. explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344030/how-can-i-use-jquery-load-to-replace-a-div-including-the-div) in answer no.3

```js
$('#area').load('/ajax/loader', function() {
    $(this).children(':first').unwrap();
});
```

2. `$("#area").load("something.html #area > *");`** loads the entire page and then jquery parses the unwanted contents. So, it's definitely a waste of bandwith and browser resources.

**Clarifications needed:**

1. Which among the 2 solution for Problem 1 is most appropriate, elegant and clean approach and is also cross browser compatible (heard some issues with using '**> ***').
2. Is there any way where I can load only the contents of the required page instead of loading the whole page and parse it on the client side.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

> 1. Which among the 2 solution for Problem 1 is most appropriate, elegant and clean approach and is also cross browser compatible (heard some issues with using '> *').

```
$("#area").load("something.html #area > *");
```

This is the most succinct answer to your issue. Use of the descendant selector should not be an issue, although the catch-all `*` is a little unsightly.

> 2. Is there any way where I can load only the contents of the required page instead of loading the whole page and parse it on the client side.

No. When the request is made the response is always the same - the HTML of the entire page. It is only the magic that jQuery performs in the background to select the elements you want which makes it appear that only part of the page was retrieved.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that out man. But about second concern, I am open to use anything other than .load() if it saves bandwidth......

Comment: No matter what method you use, the bandwidth used would be the same. When you make a request to an endpoint, you will always receive the same amount of data back.

Comment: but doesn't it depend on the amount of data returned at all !!

Comment: That's my point. The amount of data returned in the request is *always* the same. The difference is that jQuery extracts the part of it relevant to the selector provided when using `load()` so the amount you actually *see* changes.

Comment: Thanks man, that's a relief. Hey could you please take a look at my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29333278/how-to-have-a-floatright-element-with-a-text-block-without-the-text-overlapping... Feels like it's pretty simple, but I'm not able to figure it out