# Hide a div of the child using AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, back-button

I am loading pages using AJAX. In every web page I have 2 div common - header div and content div. Now when I navigate from one one page to another than I load the content div of the next page into the current page by using

`$("#content").load(URL+" #content");`

Now as I am using AJAX to load pages so I am changing the URL and manipulating history using History API.
So now when someone press the back button of the browser then there is a problem, both the header div of both the pages is being showed during loading but disappears after loading is finished . So can anyone help me how to hide the header div of the loading page.

Here is the code that I am using to handle back button of browser

```
  function swap(href) {

   var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
   x.className = "topnav";
   var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
   req.open("GET",
       "http://localhost/" +
         href.split("/").pop(),
       false);
   req.send(null);

   if (req.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = req.responseText;
      $("#content").load(" #content");
      return true;
   }

      return false;
  }

  window.addEventListener("popstate", function(e) {
     swap(location.pathname);
     e.preventDefault();
  });
```

Comment: Not sure if it's related to the problem, but `$("#content").load(URL+" #content");` is generally wrong. You're nesting the new `#content` inside the old `#content`, not replacing it, so you end up with duplicate IDs.

Comment: I have more than 10 pages and each page loads data dynamically from server and I have some task which needs to continue while navigating so i am loading the content partially and hence I am using the above method. So if it is wrong could you suggest any better solution.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344030/how-can-i-use-jquery-load-to-replace-a-div-including-the-div for how to replace instead of nesting.

Comment: I tried those solution but it did not worked some solutions are loading the whole html page instead of the specific div and some are not showing any data

Comment: They look like they should work to me.

Comment: `var id = 1;  
  var strURL = "next.php?"; 
        $.ajax({
        url: strURL
        }).done(function(data) { 
       $("#content").load(strURL+" #content", id);
     });` This is my actual function to load and I changed this according to the accepted answer in the link that you have given but it loaded full page then I saw the edit but it gave a blank page.

Comment: So you changed to `$.get(strURL + " #content", {id: id}, function(result) { $("#content").replaceWith(result); })`?

Comment: I tried these `$.get(strURl+" #content", function(data) {
     $("#content").replaceWith(data);
});` it did not worked and loaded the full html page and I also tried using `$.get(strURl+" #content", function(data) {
     $("#content").replaceWith($(data).find("#content"));;
});` it gave a blank div and I also tried other solution like `$("#content").load(strUrl+" #content > *");` it also did not worked.

Comment: Oh, you're right. Adding the fragment ID to the URL is specific to `.load()`, it doesn't work with `$.get`.

Comment: So could you please help with other solution. Or is there any way that I can select the top header div and hide it. This problem only occurs during loading time after loading is finished then the header of the second page gets hidden automatically but it creates a bad impression during loading so I need to solve it

Comment: Why are you mixing `XMLHttpRequest` with `.load()`? That's sending a second AJAX request, is that really what you want to do?

Comment: `document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = req.responseText;` replaces the content, then `$("#content").load(...)` replaces it again.

Comment: The `if(req.status)` code needs to be in the `onreadystatechange` handler of the XMLHttpRequest object.

Comment: As already I told as I am manipulating history using History API so during back button event of browser it is creating problem. Now i am not very expert in AJAX if I use `document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = req.responseText;` then two header div gets displayed and if I use only `$("#content").load(...)` then it does not work

Comment: I have taken History Api reference from [here](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work. It wraps the response in a DIV in case `#content` is the outermost element, since `.find()` only searches contents.

```js
function swap(href) {
  $("#myTopNav").addClass("topnav");
  var url = href.split('/').pop();
  $.get('http://localhost/' + url, function(response) {
      var fragment = $("<div>", {
        html: response
      });
      $("#content").replaceWith(fragment.find("#content"));
    }
  });
}

window.addEventListener("popstate", function(e) {
  swap(location.pathname);
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: I tried this is my server it is working fine for URL without any values appended in the URL.But if the URL contains some value then those are not being passed as my website uses parameter in the URL so I think it should be little modified

Comment: What does `console.log(url)` look like when that happens?

Comment: There is no error there but still it is not working. You can see my [website](https://baahi.xomoy.com)

Comment: I never asked about an error, I wanted to know if `console.log(url)` shows the URL parameters.

Comment: `location.pathname` is just the pathname part of the URL, it doesn't include the query parameters. Try using `location.href`.

Comment: Thanks a lot your solution helped me a lot. I have a one small problem related to this. Since I am passing the url like https://example.com/ in `$.get('http://localhost/' + url, function(response)` now if anyone visits https://www.example.com then it does not work. I tried using `$.get(location.pathname+"/" + url, function(response)` , it is working for all webpages like example.com/page1 , example.com/page2 but not working on the home page i.e. https://example.com

Comment: Pass an empty string as the `url` argument in that case.